How set custom header to Puppeteer response?
I have puppeteer browser
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteerConfig)
    pages = await browser.pages();
    page = pages[0];

    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    page.on('request', async (request) => {
        const url = request.url().toString()
        const frame = request.frame()
        if(frame?._parentId) {
            console.log('================ REQUEST IFRAME ===================')
            request.continue()
        } else {
            console.log('================ REQUEST ===================')
            request.continue()
        }
    })

    await page.goto(`${host}`, { waitUntil: ["networkidle0", "domcontentloaded"] });

when I get a response, I get an error that there is no header 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp'.
I need it on my server for shared memory to work.
How can I add this header to the response method ?

What's the value of host? I don't see you working with any responses. Did you mean you need this on the request header?
